# Creating unique Mongoose objects from CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

Let's say that I have a CSV containing information that needs to be parsed into different Mongoose objects. I need to either find or create a "User" based on a some information in the CSV file.  If I run this, however, it will create a new User each time, since this does not wait until the database save has finished to execute the rest of the CSV.

```
fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  parse(data, function(err, output) {
    if (err) throw err;

    User.findOne({name: output[0] }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (!user) {
        var user = new User({ name: output[0] });
        user.save(function(err, user) {
          anotherFunctionWithRestOfData(user, output);
        });
      } else {
        anotherFunctionWithRestOfData(output);
      }
    });
  })
})
```

How can I control this so that duplicate data is not being saved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [async's eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) method.

I assume that *output* is an array of users. Async's *eachSeries* will iterate over an array, process an item and, once the callback method is called, go to the next item in array :

```
fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    parse(data, function(err, output) {
        if (err) throw err;

        async.eachSeries(output, function(user, callback){
            // do your stuff with user
            // when it's done, go to the next one by calling callback
            callback(err);
        },function(err){
            // handle errors
        });

    })
})
```